# Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Estou seguindo [esse tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chatbot-ionic-dialogflow#introduction) para criar um chatbot do link abaixo, e ta dando esse erro, alguem pode me ajudar com o erro? o erro e no arquivo server.js ou no dialogflow.js?

dialogflow.js

```
const axios = require('axios')
const accessToken = process.env.DIALOGFLOW_ACCESS_TOKEN
const baseURL = 'https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910'

module.exports = {

send (message) {

    const data = {
      query: message,
      lang: 'pt-BR',
      sessionId: '123456789!@#$%'
    }
    return axios.post(baseURL, data, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
    })
  }
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const Pusher = require('pusher')
const cors = require('cors')
require('dotenv').config()
const shortId = require('shortid')
const dialogFlow = require('./dialogFlow')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID,
  key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
  secret: process.env.PUSHER_APP_SECRET,
  cluster: 'eu',
  encrypted: true
})

app.post('/message', async (req, res) => {
  // simulate actual db save with id and createdAt added
  console.log(req.body);

  const chat = {
    ...req.body,
    id: shortId.generate(),
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
  }

  //update pusher listeners

  pusher.trigger('chat-bot', 'chat', chat)

  const message = chat.message;
  const response = await dialogFlow.send(message);

  // trigger this update to our pushers listeners

  pusher.trigger('chat-bot', 'chat', {
    message: `${response.data.result.fulfillment.speech}`,
    type : 'bot',
    createdAt : new Date().toISOString(),
    id: shortId.generate()
  })

  res.send(chat)
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => console.log('Listening at 5000'))
```

erro

> ```
> module.js:549
>      throw err;
>      ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './dialogFlow'
>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>      at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>      at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>      at Object.<anonymous> (/home/marco/Documentos/trabalho/chatbot/chatbotapp/server.js:7:20)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
> ```

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que foi relatado o nome do arquivo é `dialogflow.js` e você está importando `dialogFlow`. Utilize o `require` da forma a seguir, caso os arquivos estejam na mesma pasta:

```
const dialogFlow = require('./dialogflow');
```